# Using concurrency in nested for loop? (Brute force)

Tags: loops, go, concurrency, crypt

I'm adapting code from a C program I made in class & I'm trying to convert all the programs I've written in C into Go in order to learn the language. I'm not quite "getting" concurrency yet though. How would I apply concurrency to a nested for loop? The current iteration of my program is SLOW, much slower than if i would have written in C.

Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "unsafe"
)

// #cgo LDFLAGS: -lcrypt
// #define _GNU_SOURCE
// #include <crypt.h>
// #include <stdlib.h>
import "C"

// credit for this solution goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109915/what-is-gos-equivalent-to-pythons-crypt-crypt
// for showing that you can wrap go in C via CGO
// crypt wraps C library crypt_r
func crypt(key, salt string) string {
    data := C.struct_crypt_data{}
    ckey := C.CString(key)
    csalt := C.CString(salt)
    out := C.GoString(C.crypt_r(ckey, csalt, &data))
    C.free(unsafe.Pointer(ckey))
    C.free(unsafe.Pointer(csalt))
    return out
}

func main() {
    if len(os.Args) != 2 {
        fmt.Println("Usage: ./cracker k")
        return
    }
    cipher := os.Args[1]
    var guess [5]byte
    for i := 65; i < 123; i++ {
        if i >= 91 && i <= 96 {

        } else {
            guess[0] = byte(i)
            if cipher == crypt(string(guess[:1]), "50") {
                fmt.Println(string(guess[:1]))
                return
            }
            fmt.Println(string(guess[:1]))
            for j := 65; j < 123; j++ {
                if j >= 91 && j <= 96 {
                } else {
                    guess[1] = byte(j)
                    if cipher == crypt(string(guess[:2]), "50") {
                        fmt.Println(string(guess[:2]))
                        return
                    }
                    fmt.Println(string(guess[:2]))
                    for k := 65; k < 123; k++ {
                        if k >= 91 && k <= 96 {
                        } else {
                            guess[2] = byte(k)
                            if cipher == crypt(string(guess[:3]), "50") {
                                fmt.Println(string(guess[:3]))
                                return
                            }
                            fmt.Println(string(guess[:3]))
                            for l := 65; l < 123; l++ {
                                if l >= 91 && l <= 96 {
                                } else {
                                    guess[3] = byte(l)
                                    if cipher == crypt(string(guess[:4]), "50") {
                                        fmt.Println(string(guess[:4]))
                                        return
                                    }
                                    fmt.Println(string(guess[:4]))
                                    for m := 65; m < 123; m++ {
                                        if m >= 91 && m <= 96 {
                                        } else {
                                            guess[4] = byte(m)
                                            if cipher == crypt(string(guess[:5]), "50") {
                                                fmt.Println(string(guess[:5]))
                                                return
                                            }
                                            fmt.Println(string(guess[:5]))
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The purpose of the program is to brute force a DES hash, it will work on any password up to 5 characters in length (thus, 5 nested for loops).

Comment: [Concurrency is not Parallelism](https://youtu.be/cN_DpYBzKso), and the latter is what you want to mount a brute force in a reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will not rewrite your code but I can give you a sample solution so you can fill in blanks.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
)

func produce(in chan string) {
    defer close(in)
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        in <- fmt.Sprintf("%d", i)
    }
}

func consume(in, out chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for s := range in {
        if s == "500" {
            out <- s
        }
    }
}

func stop(out chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    wg.Wait()
    close(out)
}

func main() {
    in, out := make(chan string), make(chan string)
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    go produce(in)
    for i := 0; i < runtime.NumCPU(); i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go consume(in, out, wg)
    }
    go stop(out, wg)
    fmt.Println(<-out)
}
```

The idea is to produce password proposals in producer and push heavy computation into consumers. There will be as many consumers as CPUs. Producer signals end of work by closing `in` channel. Consumers pick up the next password proposal form the `in` channel and try computing the hash. If they succeed they put the password into the `out` channel.

Stopping the program is a little bit tricky. We need a stoping routine to wait for either all consumers or for the cracked password.

Comment: The `main` returns after the first value is sent through `out`. It makes sense, but the `stop` goroutine becomes completely useless as it won't block anything. Maybe you should not use it without`go`.

Comment: If the program does not find password then it would block forever at reading from the `out` channel. Function `stop` will wait untill all consumers are finished and then close the channel to signal there is nothing found.

Comment: Ah I did not think that. You are right.

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you for this. I implemented the concurrent version of my program and there was a +300% improvement in execution time!